# Bitrate and codec questions: do we want those or not?

Tags: discussion

We've been getting a lot of bitrate/codec questions that are on a very basic level. They are mostly concerning fundamentals of the topic.
Do we want this kind of stuff here? Just asking..

Answer (score 7):

My answer: No, we do not. No basic bitrate/codec questions here, please.

Comment: thanks for your response (and i agree). upvote if you also agree with jay.

Comment: Yep, I have been trying to think of a bit rate question which could be on topic here and I can't.

Comment: If memory serves, we've had multiple sample rate questions on SSD before which I would consider on-topic. But the only question of bitrate/codec relevance that I would see here would be regarding backup / long-term storage of recordings and the benefits of compressed vs uncompressed files. But honestly, even that is stretching things.

Comment: What is the distinction between basic bitrate/codec questions and advanced bitrate/codec questions?

Comment: If there is one, and it is clearly stated that this distinction is a difficult issue, then maybe we could allow it. But I personally think there are better places to ask these questions. And more specifically it would be very technical question which are not the main topic at a sound DESIGN forum/q&a site. We like to focus on design decisions.

Answer (score 1):

If we do want one, we want one question to rule them all and all others should be closed as duplicate of that one.  Bit rate particularly is highly content dependent and can't readily be addressed by this community outside of a general case.

Codecs might have a little bit more of a place, but again, I think one master community wiki question that we can update if an additional codec is asked about is all that is necessary.

I do think that questions about encoding are relevant to the final product of many aspects of sound, but I do think a one size fits all kind of answer is as far as we can reasonably take it.

Comment: Personally I could take it or leave it at all, but I think having one question we can point to as the answer would make the site more helpful while also keeping questions like this from becoming common.