# Are questions about sound quality off-topic here?

Tags: discussion

Examples of questions on sound quality:

- [When does playing 320 Kbps MP3 instead of FLAC matter?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/q/27621/6753)
- https://sound.stackexchange.com/q/28041/6753

Is that on-topic or off-topic here? Does that qualify as [basic bitrate and codec questions, hence off-topic](https://sound.meta.stackexchange.com/q/164/6753)?

Answer (score 3):

I would say yes, these questions fall into the same category as bitrate and codec questions and would therefore be considered as off-topic as they are.